# Node-Express: filter request query and display rest of the data

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am new in Node query. I am using Node express for my backend app. I have one nested json which has three language options and inside language there are `auth`, `dashboard`, `data`, and `data1` options. I want to filter the query and display rest of the json data in my browser. for example if I type url like this: `http://localhost:5000/?namespaces=auth&languages=en,fi` then it will display language `en` and `fi's` data and from `namespaces` I want to display `auth's` data. For display the data I have created one output empty object and want to add it in my output object. but don't know how to do that.

I have share my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-filter-fwo9w?file=/src/index.js).

**This is my json data**

```
{
    "en": {
        "auth": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hi John"
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "welcomeMessage": "Hi Doe"
        },
        "data (1)": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hi Jonny"
        },
        "data": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hi Monty"
        }
    },
    "fi": {
        "auth": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Moi name "
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "welcomeMessage": "Moi dashboard"
        },
        "data (1)": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Moi data 1"
        },
        "data": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Moi data"
        }
    },
    "sv": {
        "auth": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hej John"
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "welcomeMessage": "Hej dashboard"
        },
        "data (1)": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hej data"
        },
        "data": {
            "welcomeMessage3": "Hej data"
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my express app**

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 5000
    const translationData = require('./translations'); // My json
    
    
    const filterTranslations = (namespaces, languages) => {
  let output = {};
  const translations = { ...translationData };
  console.log("I am typing Languages", languages);
  console.log("I am typing namespace", namespaces);
  for (const lng in translations) {
    console.log("languages are coming from translation json", lng);
    if (lng.length !== 0 && lng !== languages) {
      delete translations[lng];
      console.log("Delete rest of the language", lng);
    } else {
      for (const ns in translations[lng]) {
        if (ns.length !== 0 && ns !== namespaces) {
          delete translations[lng][ns];
          console.log("delete rest of the Namespace", ns);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
};
    
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send(
        filterTranslations(
          req.query.namespaces,
          req.query.languages,
        )
      )
    })
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you expect? I', reworking your code and will provide an answer as soon as I have that.

Comment: if put api url: `http://localhost:5000/?namespaces=auth&languages=en,fi`

output:

`{"en": {
    "auth": {
      "welcomeMessage3": "Hi John"
    },
   },
  "fi": {
    "auth": {
      "welcomeMessage3": "Moi John "
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes :

- the function `filterTranslations` should return a value, here `translations`,
- the conditions in your `if` statement is not correct : `lng !== languages`, in your example, `languages = 'en,fi'` and `lng` will be `en` or `fi`. Look at `String.includes( searchString [, position ])` or `split` your `languages` and use `Array.includes( searchElement[, fromIndex])`.

Hoping I helped you, have a good day !

Comment: I did not get it :/, Can you please show me in : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-filter-fwo9w?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: In your `if` statement : `if (lng.length !== 0 && lng !== languages) {...}`, your are testing `lng='fi' !== languages='fi,en'`, with `Array.split(',')` and `Array.includes(lng)` you will have what you want: like this : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-filter-forked-ktin7?file=/src/index.js) -- I update with an early exit if no namespace or languages is set.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. you have made my day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do I think you overcomplicate things.

First of all passing a comma separated string as a parameter is not the best idea as you would have to turn it into an array in the backend by splitting the string in the comma. It's best if it's an array to begin with. That means that your url would be :

http://localhost:8080/?namespaces=auth&languages[]=en&languages[]=fi

Then the function that handles this would be:

```
const filterTranslations = (namespaces, languages) => {
  let output = [];
  const translations = { ...translationData };
  //languages are now an array
  for (let l in languages) {
    let lng = languages[l];
    // for each language you send as a parameter you push a new object in your output with the language as a key and the values
    output.push({[lng]:translations[lng]});
  }
  return output;
};
```

The expected output is the following:

```
[
    {
        "en": {
            "auth": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Hi John"
            },
            "dashboard": {
                "welcomeMessage": "Hi Doe"
            },
            "data (1)": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Hi Jonny"
            },
            "data": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Hi Monty"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "fi": {
            "auth": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Moi name "
            },
            "dashboard": {
                "welcomeMessage": "Moi dashboard"
            },
            "data (1)": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Moi data 1"
            },
            "data": {
                "welcomeMessage3": "Moi data"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I still don't get the data. My goal was filter the data out, for example: if I put url like this `http://localhost:5000/?namespaces=auth&languages=en,fi` then it will remove the language `sv` then when I type namespaces `auth` then it will remove `dashboard`, `data`, `data (1)`.

Comment: I have share my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-filter-fwo9w?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: You don't need to remove the data, you just select part of them.

Comment: I am not planning to removing. My goal is not create different api end points and display it browser. Sorry my english is not good :(. But did you get what I mean ?

Comment: Exactly, so if you replace the function you have with the one I posted here you will get the data you want. you don't need to create a new end point for that. Just try it. Also you obviously don't understand how your code works. When you do "delete translations[lng][ns];" you don't update the json file data, you just update the in-memory json object.

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you mate!
if you try the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-filter-solution-78p5q?file=/src/index.js) and in url paste this :`https://78p5q.sse.codesandbox.io/?namespaces=auth&languages=fi`.